# Mudar as propriedades de um objeto adicionado em um array várias vezes acaba mudando todos os elementos

Tags: javascript

Quando vou inserir outro produto na minha lista de compras a mesma substitui o primeiro item e duplica o segundo:

```js
var arrayCompras = [];
let product = {
  nome: "",
  preco: 0,
  mostrar: function () {
    product.nome = document.formulario.nomeProduto.value;
    product.preco = document.formulario.valorProduto.value;
    const productAlreadyExists = arrayCompras.find(
      (compra) => compra === product.nome
    );
    if (product.nome != "" && !productAlreadyExists) {
      arrayCompras.push(product);
    }
    document.formulario.listaProdutos.value = "";

    for (var compra of arrayCompras) {
      document.formulario.listaProdutos.value +=
        compra.nome + " -> " + compra.preco + " €" + "\n";
    }
    document.formulario.listaProdutos.value += `\n\nNúmero Total de Produtos: ${arrayCompras.length};`;
    document.formulario.nomeProduto.value = "";
    document.formulario.valorProduto.value = "";
  },
};
```

```css
* {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form name="formulario">
  <input type="text" name="nomeProduto" placeholder="Produto" />
  <input type="number" name="valorProduto" placeholder="Preço" />
  <input
    type="button"
    value="Adicionar Produto"
    onclick="product.mostrar()"
  />

  <br />
  <br />
  <textarea name="listaProdutos" cols="40" rows="10" readonly></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você criou um único objeto `product` e insere ele várias vezes no array. Quando você muda `product.nome`, está portanto mudando o nome de "todos" os elementos do array, já que na verdade o que você tem é o mesmo objeto inserido várias vezes. Por isso ao mudar o nome e valor do produto, acabam ficando com todos iguais.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que foi digitado o nome "item1" e preço 100. Você seta os dados do objeto `product` e insere no array, então agora temos:

[image: array com um elemento]

Agoras vamos supor que foi digitado o nome "item2" e preço 200. Você seta esses dados do objeto `product` e insere ele no array, então agora temos:

[image: array com duas referências para o mesmo objeto]

Isso acontece porque ao inserir o objeto `product` no array, você está na verdade inserindo uma referência ao mesmo. Então se você insere ele duas vezes, tem duas referências para o mesmo objeto. E ao mudar os dados do objeto, faz com que todas as referências (e portanto todos os elementos do array) enxerguem essas mudanças.

Por isso você acaba com esta situação, de ter todos os elementos com o último valor que foi preenchido.

Para evitar isso, esqueça esse objeto e crie um novo a cada inserção:

```js
var arrayCompras = [];

function adicionar() {
    var nome = document.formulario.nomeProduto.value;
    var preco = document.formulario.valorProduto.value;
    const productAlreadyExists = arrayCompras.find(compra => compra.nome === nome);
    if (nome != "" && !productAlreadyExists) {
        // **AQUI**: em vez de inserir sempre o mesmo objeto product, crie sempre um novo
        arrayCompras.push({ nome, preco });
    }
    document.formulario.nomeProduto.value = "";
    document.formulario.valorProduto.value = "";
}

// separei as funções de adicionar e mostrar, já que são coisas diferentes
function mostrar() {
    document.formulario.listaProdutos.value = "";
    for (var compra of arrayCompras) {
      document.formulario.listaProdutos.value += compra.nome + " -> " + compra.preco + " €" + "\n";
    }
    document.formulario.listaProdutos.value += `\n\nNúmero Total de Produtos: ${arrayCompras.length};`;
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form name="formulario">
  <input type="text" name="nomeProduto" placeholder="Produto" />
  <input type="number" name="valorProduto" placeholder="Preço" />
  <input type="button" value="Adicionar Produto" onclick="adicionar();mostrar()" />

  <br />
  <br />
  <textarea name="listaProdutos" cols="40" rows="10" readonly></textarea>
</form>
```

Repare que agora eu sempre crio um novo objeto ao inserir no array: `{ nome, preco }` cria um novo objeto contendo o nome e preço que foram digitados.

Na verdade esta sintaxe é um atalho para `{ 'nome': nome, 'preco': preco }`, mas de qualquer forma, ele cria um objeto contendo as propriedades `nome` e `preco`, cujos valores são os dados que foram digitados.

Desta forma cada elemento do array é um objeto diferente, eliminando o problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica e por me mostrar onde eu estava errando.

Comment: @Henrique Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema